# MySQL IN Clause with comma inside

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question on MySQL IN Clause where I dont know how to start the code.

Original

```
$merchant_separated = implode(",", $array);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assigned_id WHERE id NOT IN ($merchant_separated) AND viewable = 'True'");
```

What I have now in my DB table is the code below:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_purchased");
whil($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
$r['merchantid_imploded'] ='9,6,2,3,5,4,1,7,8'
$r['productnumber'] = 'Fjduensd'
$r['Title'] = 'Animation Csr'
$r['Product Name'] = 'Inwards Development'
```

What I want to do is to just fetch like this code below. It can't work because in the query there is this field `merchantid_imploded 9,6,2,3,5,4,1,7,8` the clientid cant fetch with the comma.

```
$clientid = 2
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_purchased WHERE merchantid_imploded IN ($clientid) ");
```

What I want to do is just to fetch this Merchant With this Product Purchased

Please advise

Comment: Output your SQL before executing the query and post it here.

Comment: Translation: merchantid_imploded is a comma-separated field containing ids of merchants who bought the specified item.  OP wants to find all items purchased by a given merchant (in the example, with id #2).

Answer (score 2):

Well, your design for merchantid_imploded is going to cause you a lot of trouble.  You should store those numbers in a separate table, one per row, along with the product number.  Look up the term "database normalization" to learn more about this.  The best time to fix this is *now*, before you commit more programming effort to this design.  (At the same time, consider using parameterized queries to protect your code against SQL injection attacks.)

That said, MySQL (uniquely among SQL databases) offers a number of features to let you do what you want.  One possibility is FIND_IN_SET:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($clientid, merchantid_imploded) > 0
```

Also, plain old IN should work in MySQL assuming you put the arguments in the right place:

```
WHERE $clientid IN merchantid_imploded
```

Comment: hi all thanks for the reply. <br/>

Because everytime i am using a implode to find whats inside. But i have never tried to find it on implode in a imploded query.<br/><br/>

It means for eg.<br/>

Product one = Merchant 1, Merchant 2, Merchant 4<br/>
If Merchant 1 login to the site he will then see Product One is the one being purchased.<br><b>

This is just a history records because this is a function where by it gets the codes from each merchants to see which quotation is cheaper.
<br/><br>

Which i can think of is using an in_array function to deal with it. but i think is not visable